# what would be the best way to check duplicates

Tags: mysql

What would be the best way to find out or to check all the `prs_code`(s) having a duplicate of `item_code`?

[image: Example of SQL rows]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group by and look for any counts of 2 or more (they'll be dupes):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt, prs_code, item_code
FROM whatever_you_call_your_table
GROUP BY prs_code, item_code
HAVING cnt > 1
```

Comment: `from tbl_name` should be there :P otherwise it will throw syntax error

Comment: Oh, derp. Thanks, my friend.

Answer (score 0):

Query:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_name
GROUP BY item_code
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```